# VB.Net Application does not return all Oracle data rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

I have a VB.Net application that we have been using for a while. Recently someone pointed out that the dataset we load into the program on load for our part numbers is missing some records.

I have tried different variations of the select statement. I have edited the application dropdown menu attributes to make the dropdown larger, trying to get it to show more issues. I also tried rewriting the loop which adds my dataset rows into the items in the dropdown. I put a message box in to give me the record count and there are about eighty records missing from the dataset.

I confirmed this by opening my database client and running the exact same select statement against the database. Running the select statement on the database client returns all the rows, but if I run it using the data adapter and fill the data set there are records missing. Below is my code. Any suggestions to what might be happening?

```
'Load Part #s
OraSQL = "SELECT Part_No FROM TableName Where Contract = 'ContractName' AND Part_No Like 'PartPrefix%' AND Pat_No NOT LIKE = 'WrongPartPrefix%'"
OraDa = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(OraSQL, OraCon)
OraCon.Open()
OraDa.Fill(OraDs, "Part")
OraCon.Close()
'Populate Combo Box with Active Machines
SelectedRow = 0

' Load items into dropdown
        TotalRows = OraDs.Tables("Part").Rows.Count
        SelectedRow = 0
        TxtPartNo.Items.Add("")
        While SelectedRow < TotalRows
            TxtPartNo.Items.Add(OraDs.Tables("Part").Rows(SelectedRow).Item("Part_No"))
            SelectedRow += 1
        End While
```

Edit: I updated the SQL statement to look more like the actual SQL statement I am using. There is only one WHERE statement followed by AND operators.

Edit Again: I rewrote the function to utilize a data reader rather than a data adapter to see if rewriting in a more efficient manner might help. However, I am still getting the same results. Below is the code block:

```
Using OraCon

    Dim command As Odbc.OdbcCommand = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(OraSQL, OraCon)

    OraCon.Open()
    Dim reader As Odbc.OdbcDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    If reader.HasRows Then
        Do While reader.Read()
            TxtPartNo.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
        Loop
    End If
    OraCon.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Might be erroneous, but the line `TotalRows = MyDs.Tables("Machine").Rows.Count` references a table called `Machine` and later on you ask for the table called `Part` in `TxtPartNo.Items.Add(OraDs.Tables("Part").Rows(SelectedRow).Item("Part_No"))`

Comment: Sorry, that line actually references another dataset that we grab machine information from. It does not do anything to the part_no dataset.

Comment: I would suggest that, for the sake of testing, you use the query "*SELECT COUNT(Part_No) FROM TableName Where Contract = 'ContractName' Where Part_No Like 'PartPrefix%'*" and call `ExecuteScalar` and then execute the same query against your database directly. If they come back with different values then the only explanations are that something is corrupt on your system or you are using two different databases.

Comment: I also see two unrelated issues with the quality of your code.  Firstly, if you're just going to add the valu4es as items directly, use a data reader rather than a data adapter and a `DataTable`.  If you are going to use a data adapter and a `DataTable`, bind the `DataTable` to the control rather and don't use a `DataSet` to hold a single `DataTable`. Finally, if you are going to use a loop, a `While` loop there is a silly choice. That's a job for a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Another issue I see is the statement `"SELECT Part_No FROM TableName Where Contract = 'ContractName' Where Part_No Like 'PartPrefix%'"` is incorrect and won't work at all. - Too many `WHERE` statements

Comment: "running the exact same select statement " So, you have a Contract value that is ContractName and a Part_No like the string PartPrefix%?

Comment: @JayV I saw that the statement I am using only has the one WHERE statement followed by AND operators to further filter the part numbers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I changed the code to try and make it a little better quality. Still not able to get accurate results. It's a legacy application. A lot of it needs to be redone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using our test data source in the program and the production database with the client. Like an idiot. Thank you to everyone who helped!